# how would I go around combining the second subquery?

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, subquery

This is my first time posting on stack overflow but I've done some research using this board before. I've been watching tutorials but Im confused as to how to nest the second sub query for the following:

```
select sum(completion.close - induction.entry) as cycle1
from 
    (select wo_status_history.entry_date as entry 
     from wo_status_history
     where wo_status_history.wos_auto_key='342') induction
    --(select wo_status_history.entry_Date as close
    --from wo_status_history
    --where wo_status_history.wos_auto_key='310') completion
```

I can get the bottom 2 queries to work fine individually, and when nesting only one it works fine, but Im just not sure how I would pull the second.
Would I nest the third query in the second one? New to SQL, would appreciate any pointers!

Comment: I am not sure what result you are expecting to get by using `sum` aggregation on a date, unless your date field is some kind of epoch

Comment: My bad Gandalf, I see what you mean. I think my approach is flawed. I am trying to determine the elapsed time between the two timestamps, the result would be tied to a column in the table thats an identifier, its called woo_auto_key

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output. Clearly we are not sure what your desired result looks like

Answer (score 0):

Use `conditional aggregation` as following:

```
Select max(case when wos_auto_key='310' then entry_date end) 
       - Max(case when wos_auto_key='342' then entry_date end)
  from wo_status_history
 where wo_status_history.wos_auto_key in ('310','342')
```

**Note**: I assume that the `wos_auto_key` is primary key and `entry_date` is `date`.

Cheers!!

Comment: Apologies; I think I'm making a mistake! Thank you for the help, but how would I determine the elapsed time between the two time stamps. User Gandalf pointed out that it would not be the accurate result

Comment: If entrydate is of date data type then dufference between two dates are number of days between those two dates. You can multiply that number with 24 to get number of hours between date